# iPhone - Text Displayed from Database when Buttons Pushed

Tags: iphone, database, xcode, sqlite

I am new to the iPhone. I am writing an App that will display text information based on the sequence someone presses on a set of buttons. There are five (5) Tables that each have about sixty (60) responses that are about the size of the sample below: There will be a total of maybe three hundred (300) unique responses. I want to be able to update these 300 unique answers each 6 months or so in an updated version. What is the best storage and retrieval method? SQlite?, Core Data? some other method?

> **SAMPLE:**
>   *Hbts tb mhkx h fhvbrhblx nmprxssnbn hnd bx rxghrdxd
>   hs h spxcnhl pxrsbnhlnty. Ns thxrxfbrx cbnsthntly
>   bn thx whtch tb sxx whxthxr hx ns succxxdnng
>   nn thns hnd hbw bthxrs hrx rxhctnng tb hnm; thns
>   mhkxs hnm fxxl thht hx ns nn cbntrbl. Usxs thctncs
>   clxvxrly nn brdxr tb bbthnn nnfluxncx hnd spxcnhl rxcbgnntnbn.
>   Buwcxptnblx tb thx xsthxtnc br brngnnh**

Answer (score 0):

You could do a plist or series of plists. 300 may not really warrant a database. And plists would be very simple to update.